# updating text files

Tags: java, text

I have two text files(txt1 and txt2). Whenever a data is entered in txt1 I want the counter to increment in txt2. I am using windows xp. 
Is this possible? How can this be done? 

I want to create a process in windows that keeps looking for any changes made in the text file.

Comment: Who adds data top txt1? Your application or other process?

Comment: Look at this tutorial: [Watching a Directory for Changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File txt1 = new File("txt1");
File txt2 = new File("txt2");
long lastmodified = txt1.lastModified();
while(true) {
    if (txt1.lastModified()>lastModified) {
        // Read from txt2
        // Increment value or initialize to 0;
        // Write new value to txt2;
        lastModified = txt2.lastModified();
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Best approach, but it requires that the file is stored each time *a data is entered*. And that we don't have two changes within a second (or within SLEEP_TIME ;) )

Comment: True, but the question is kind of vague, so hard to do better. More context would help us provide a more adequate response.

Comment: @Andreas_D:yes your answer is something close to what I wanted.

Comment: Credits go to Guillaume, that's *his* answer :)